# Classic ASP sort list of dates by year, then by month

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a list of dates, which are in this format: YYYY-MM-DD

I would like to be able to sort them in descending order by year (2013, 2012, 2011), and then ascending order by month (January, February, March,...). So what I'm looking for is:

```
2013-01-01
2013-02-01
2013-03-01
2013-04-01
2013-05-01

2012-01-01
2012-02-01
2012-03-01
...
2012-12-01

2011-01-01
2011-02-01
2011-03-01
...
2011-12-01
```

Note, the list for the current year would be incomplete until December, so that's why it only goes to 2013-05-01. Previous years would be complete from January-December.

I did a bubble-sort similar to this:

```
For i = 0 to Ubound(dateArray)
    For j = i + 1 to Ubound(dateArray) 
        if dateArray(i) > dateArray(j) then
            tempDate = dateArray(i)         
            dateArray(i) = dateArray(j)
            dateArray(j) = tempDate
        end if
    Next  
Next
```

but that gives me a list that looks like this:

```
2011-01-01
2011-02-01
2011-03-01
...
2011-12-01

2012-01-01
2012-02-01
2012-03-01
...
2012-12-01

2013-01-01
2013-02-01
2013-03-01
2013-04-01
2013-05-01
```

Close, but not quite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this one before... I think this is how I solved it.

```
For i = 0 to Ubound(dateArray)
    For j = i + 1 to Ubound(dateArray) 
        if (year(dateArray(i)) < year(dateArray(j))) or (year(dateArray(i)) = year(dateArray(j)) and month(dateArray(i)) > month(dateArray(j)))then
            tempDate = dateArray(i)         
            dateArray(i) = dateArray(j)
            dateArray(j) = tempDate
        end if
    Next  
Next
```

Comment: DANGEROUS CODE: solves the special case (all first-of-month dates) but fails in general (different days of month).

Comment: Good catch, Ekkehard.  I only used the dates provided and randomized.  This solution only solves the problem if the day of the month is always the first.  I also recommend using the solution by Ansgar Wiechers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to sort ascending when the year is the same in both dates, and descending when the year is different:

```
Sub SwapValues(ByRef a, ByRef b)
    buf = a : a = b : b = buf
End Sub

...

If Year(dateArray(i)) = Year(dateArray(j)) Then
  If dateArray(i) > dateArray(j) Then
    SwapValues dateArray(i), dateArray(j)
  End If
Else
  If dateArray(i) < dateArray(j) Then
    SwapValues dateArray(i), dateArray(j)
  End If
End If
```

I added a procedure for swapping the values to simplify the code a little.

Comment: CORRECT SOLUTION for all cases, because it takes the days into account.